# Segue in popover dismiss completion crashing

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a customer that is experiencing crashes on the following piece of code. We haven't had any luck reproducing it, and it has been running smoothly for years in the published app, until we distributed this beta in TestFlight:

```swift
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
    if let _ = self.activeAlert {
        self.activeAlert?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            // crashes here
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "finished_calibration", sender: self)
        })
    } else {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "finished_calibration", sender: self)
    }
    
})
```

this is the stack trace

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1bde8d344 __exceptionPreprocess + 228 (NSException.m:199)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1bdba2cc0 objc_exception_throw + 60 (objc-exception.mm:565)
2   UIKitCore                       0x1c194af8c -[UIViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] + 284 (UIViewController.m:3979)
3   iOSense                         0x10016be68 partial apply for closure #1 in closure #4 in ODOCalGetDataViewController.catchNotification(notification:) + 48
4   iOSense                         0x1001f24b4 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 28 (<compiler-generated>:0)
5   UIKitCore                       0x1c195bd10 -[UIViewController dismissViewControllerWithTransition:completion:] + 1276 (UIViewController.m:7909)
6   UIKitCore                       0x1c195b720 -[UIViewController _performCoordinatedPresentOrDismiss:animated:] + 528 (UIViewController.m:7837)
7   UIKitCore                       0x1c195df68 -[UIViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:] + 148 (UIViewController.m:8335)
8   iOSense                         0x10016b334 closure #5 in ODOCalGetDataViewController.catchNotification(notification:) + 200 (ODOCalGetDataViewController.swift:108)
9   iOSense                         0x1001f24b4 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 28 (<compiler-generated>:0)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x1bdb2e134 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1408)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x1bdb2f5ac _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:495)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x1bdb3b7d4 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 832 (inline_internal.h:2484)
13  CoreFoundation                  0x1bde088d4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16 (CFRunLoop.c:1749)
14  CoreFoundation                  0x1bde0358c __CFRunLoopRun + 1692 (CFRunLoop.c:3069)
15  CoreFoundation                  0x1bde02bc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 480 (CFRunLoop.c:3192)
16  GraphicsServices                0x1c81eb5cc GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2246)
17  UIKitCore                       0x1c1fb5744 UIApplicationMain + 1936 (UIApplication.m:4823)
18  iOSense                         0x100120114 main + 68 (ISenseApplication.swift:13)
19  libdyld.dylib                   0x1bdc7f384 start + 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
8 iOSense 0x10016b334 closure #5 in ODOCalGetDataViewController.catchNotification(notification:) + 200 (ODOCalGetDataViewController.swift:108)
```

**Frame 8** in the stack trace shows that the execution was initiated by firing a notification. Can you make sure that the `UIViewController` instance, responsible for presenting `activeAlert` was loaded from `Storyboard` before performing the segue?
You can do so by adding a sanity check to ensure that `storyboard` property is not `nil` before calling `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`.

```
guard let _ = storyboard else { return }
```

Apple Documentation for [performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621413-performsegue) says that

> The current view controller must have been loaded from a storyboard. If its storyboard property is nil, perhaps because you allocated and initialized the view controller yourself, this method throws an exception.